# Get only structure of repo folders without files

Tags: perforce, directory

I have some repo in perforce, I want to download only structure of folders without files, do you know how can I make this ?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To learn about the folders/directories that are in a certain section of your Perforce repository, you can use the `p4 dirs` command (see http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_dirs.html).

For example,

```
p4 dirs //depot/*
```

will tell you all the top-level directories under `//depot`. Suppose the list that comes back is:

```
//depot/main
//depot/r1.0
```

Then you could subsequently issue:

```
p4 dirs //depot/main/*
```

and

```
p4 dirs //depot/r1.0/*
```

to learn about the next level of directories, and so forth, until you find no further child directories under the section of the repository that you are searching.

Once you have learned the correct set of directories that correspond to the current contents of your repository in Perforce, you can issue the corresponding `mkdir` commands to make those directories on your workstation.